# How can we get the session id from a Quote object?

Tags: magento-1.9, ee-1.14.2.4

Is it possible to get sessionId from a quote object? I'm looking for a method like,

```
$quote->getEncryptedSessionId()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so you can get it from `quote` object because it is define in `session(app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php)` object like, and you can get it from session like

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getEncryptedSessionId()` .

Comment: Yes, for active session we can able to get it from session object. When a user abandon the cart, I have to pass the SID to the user in email to access the same session to continue his order process. To achieve this I'm looking for a better option instead of storing the session in table and get.

Comment: Yes, you can store in database, to detect it. But for your question you can not get it from quote object. you can get it only from session. @seeni